# How to make void other thread visit until the code block finished for windows phone animation

Tags: multithreading, windows-phone-7

I am making a top notification animation, but I don't know how to make the animation synchronous until the animation finishes. Here is the code I have:

```
public Storyboard prepareShowStory(int count, NotificationControl notifyControl)
        {
            notifyControl.textBlock1.Text = "Got" + count.ToString() + "Message";

            notifyControl.RenderTransform = new CompositeTransform();
            Storyboard story = new Storyboard();
           //From here until the annimation finish and remove LayoutRoot.Resources.Clear();
            LayoutRoot.Resources.Add("unique_id", story);

            story.Completed += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
            {
                story.Stop();
                story.Children.Clear();
                App.ViewModel.myAction -= CompletedRefresh;
                LayoutRoot.Resources.Clear();
                 //To here.
            };
            story.Begin();

            DoubleAnimation animation;
            animation = new DoubleAnimation();
            animation.AutoReverse = true;
            animation.From = -64;
            animation.To = 60;
            animation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1600));
            animation.EasingFunction = _EasingFunction;
            Storyboard.SetTargetName(animation, notifyControl.Name);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath("(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)"));
            story.Children.Add(animation);

            return story;
        }
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to return `story` after the `story.begin` has finished?

Comment: I want to clear LayoutRoot.Resources.Clear(); when the annimation finished, otherwise, if another thread come to LayoutRoot.Resources.Add("unique_id", story); agian, but annimation is not finish, the system will report error "add twice".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check the ResourceDictionary before adding to it.

```
if(!LayoutRoot.Resources.Contains("unique_id"))
   LayoutRoot.Resources.Add("unique_id", story);
```

Comment: it still report error"An item with the same key has already been added." if the function is invoked twice with limited time.    private void CompletedRefresh(int count)
        {
                 this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                {
                    var story = prepareShowStory(count, this.notificationControl1);
                    story.Begin();
                });
        }

Comment: What line throws that error and can't you do a check if the key already exists before adding?

Comment: this line report the error, LayoutRoot.Resources.Add("unique_id", story); because the annimation is not finish, I invoke the function agian, so it will report the error,but I don't know how to lock the function until the annimation finish. many thanks!!

Comment: I assume Resources is a Dictionary, so you can check if the key exists before inserting it. If it does exist, it won't add it. Check my updated answer.